# Дубли тега <title> в коде шаблона на wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Помогите убрать дублирующийся тег  в коде сайта (дубли на всех страницах) или подскажите, куда глянуть.
На сайте стоит плагин all in one seo pack, в нем стоит перезаписывать заголовки, судя по header.php тайтл вызывается только 1 раз

При его удалении тянется заголовок, который указывается в заголовке статьи, а тот, что писали в all in one seo pack пропадает, а нужно наоборот 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При отключении all in one seo pack дубль так же остается

Comment: Кривая тема скорее всего. Или ещё какой-то плагин это делает. С лечением по картинками - это к экстрасенсам.

Answer (score 0):

Отключите **все** плагины на сайте. Если проблема исчезла, по одному включайте каждый плагин и проверяйте, в какой момент проблема появится повторно. Так удастся локализовать плагин-виновник. Если при отключении всех плагинов проблема не ушла - дело в теме сайта.

Answer (score 0):

По картинке очевидно, что сео-плагин тут не причем. Его комментарий начинается после проблемы. Первым делом надо внимательно header.php смотреть, возможно дубль там находится. Если отключение плагинов тоже никаких результатов не дало, значит скачиваете сайт на компьютер, открываете Totel Comander, переходите в папку с темой, вводите в поиск комбинацию `<title>` и шерстите более подходящие по логике файлы на их наличие. Только так избавиться получится. Тоже самое могу порекомендовать провести в папке плагины, если при их отключении проблема исчезает.